# __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm getting

```
index.js:978 TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function
at eval (index.vue:20)
at Object.dqAR (pages-investment-pages-home-index.js:348)
at __webpack_require__ (index.js:854)
at fn (index.js:151)
at eval (null:1)
at Module.Hi1e (pages-investment-pages-home-index.js:177)
at __webpack_require__ (index.js:854)
at fn (index.js:151)
at eval (null:1)
at Module.bE2I (pages-investment-pages-home-index.js:320)
```

here is my code

```
const path = './'
require.context(path,false,/\.js$/)
```

it looks like the arguments of require.context can't be a varible.
because when i used like this it works fine:

```
require.context('./',false,/\.js$/)
```

i am confuse about it.

is that because of this function is belong to webpack and it's running before the compile?

thanks for ur answer.

Comment: See also different solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/74572172/12534

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The arguments passed to `require.context` [must be literals!](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext) (look at warning in the link)

In the images below the right side is the generated webpack from left side:

Using literals generates valid `__webpack_require__`:
[image: using litterals in require.context]

Using variables generated invalid `__webpack_require__`:
[image: using variable in require.context]

Comment: Is there any solution when you need to pass the path from else where and it cannot be literal, but has to be as in second case using variable?