# Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

When I try to dynamically import xml files using this code:

```
const path = require.context(`../report/${runId}/`, false, /\.xml$/);
```

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function
    at fetchData (xmlparser.js:28:1)
    at Run.getTests (Run.js:16:1)
    at Run.componentDidMount (Run.js:10:1)
    at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:23305:1)
    at commitLayoutMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24688:1)
    at commitLayoutEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24674:1)
    at commitLayoutEffects (react-dom.development.js:24612:1)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26823:1)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:26682:1)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26117:1)
```

But as soon as I import the XML files as following it works:

```
const path = require.context(`../report/1/`, false, /\.xml$/);
```

Note - runId is declared as 1, so it isn't undefined

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70548009/12534

Answer (score 1):

**--edit**: 
my answer is wrong. [stackoverflow.com/questions/54059179/what-is-require-context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059179/what-is-require-context) require.context is evaluated at compile time, so you must pass a static string, not a variable or dynamic concatenation, evaluated runtime. This is why the second example works.

Comment: still get the same error message, but thanks anyways

Comment: even with the first example?

Comment: unfortunately, yes

Comment: ok got it, my answer is wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059179/what-is-require-context require.context is evaluated at compile time, so you must pass a static string. I mean not a variable, you can't dynamically load it, you should use fetch or other Api instead, maybe a loader with Dynamic imports